# Best practice for dynamically added Web.UI.ITemplate classes

Tags: .net, asp.net

We have a couple of ASP.Net dataview column templates that are dynamically added to the dataview depending on columns selected by users.

These templated cells need to handle custom databindings:

```
public class CustomColumnTemplate: 
    ITemplate
{
    public void InstantiateIn( Control container )
    {
        //create a new label
        Label contentLabel = new Label();

        //add a custom data binding
        contentLabel.DataBinding +=
            ( sender, e ) =>
            {
                //do custom stuff at databind time
                contentLabel.Text = //bound content
            };

        //add the label to the cell
        container.Controls.Add( contentLabel );
    }
}

...

myGridView.Columns.Add( new TemplateField
    {
       ItemTemplate = new CustomColumnTemplate(),
       HeaderText = "Custom column"
    } );
```

Firstly this seems rather messy, but there is also a resource issue. The `Label` is generated, and can't be disposed in the `InstantiateIn` because then it wouldn't be there to databind.

Is there a better pattern for these controls?

Is there a way to make sure that the label is disposed after the databind and render?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have worked extensively with templated control and I have not found a better solution.

Why are you referencing the contentLable in the event handler?

The sender is the label you can cast it to the label and have the reference to the label.  Like below.

```
        //add a custom data binding
        contentLabel.DataBinding +=
            (object sender, EventArgs e ) =>
            {
                //do custom stuff at databind time
                ((Label)sender).Text = //bound content
            };
```

Then you should be able to dispose of the label reference in InstantiateIn.

Please note I have not tested this.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to make your template *itself* implement `IDisposable`, and then dispose the controls in your template's `Dispose` method. Of course this means you need some sort of collection to keep track of the controls you've created. Here is one way to go about it:

```
public class CustomColumnTemplate :
    ITemplate, IDisposable
{
    private readonly ICollection<Control> labels = new List<Control>();

    public void Dispose()
    {
        foreach (Control label in this.labels)
            label.Dispose();
    }

    public void InstantiateIn(Control container)
    {
        //create a new label
        Label contentLabel = new Label();

        this.labels.Add(contentLabel);
```

...

```
        //add the label to the cell
        container.Controls.Add( contentLabel );
    }
}
```

Now you are still faced with the problem of disposing the template. But at least your template will be a responsible memory consumer because when you call `Dispose` on the template all of its labels will be disposed with it.

**UPDATE**

[This link on MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vstscode/thread/c02bde1c-6fbd-4d25-8727-b52c2e6ceb88) suggests that perhaps it is not necessary for your template to implement `IDisposable` because the controls will be rooted in the page's control tree and automatically disposed by the framework!